# 3D thermography setup

Tags: temperature, sensor

I want to know if its possible (yet) to sense the temperature throughout a given cylinder using non-invasive techniques? Such as ultrasonic or visual imaging etc. The temperature ranges from 250-450C. Resolution is not so important.

I read some research publications; most of which place thermo-couples at various locations inside the cylinder. I want some thing non-invasive to draw a 3D graph of temperature.

Comment: The answer depends on what's inside the cylinder.

Comment: The cylinder is mostly empty. There's a small metallic cube at the base. Small amount of liquid (mainly water) will be dropped from the top surface onto the cube. This will cause a somewhat violent reaction. I have to see how does the temperature change in the surroundings of the metallic cube.

Comment: I see. Are you trying to do calorimetry this way? I don't think that's going to be particularly successful, any which way you try to do this, since what you are interested in is heat production, not temperature.

Comment: This work is not related to calorimetry. Sorry, but because of the nature of this project, I can not discuss the specifics. Yes, the reaction produces heat but my task is to measure temperature at various locations inside the cylinder over several minutes.

Comment: If the nature of your project is sensitive, then you shouldn't be discussing it on the internet. The people who may be interested in what you are doing will know what it's for. :-). Having said that, calibrated IR cameras are probably your best bet. That's going to be as accurate as you can get without physical sensors. Be careful, don't let the authorities catch you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out infrared thermometer for help. I have ever use it in my own work, but not draw a temperature-distribution as your case, only get the temperature of some objects I can't easy to get close to. But I think that will help for your case. But also note that, the accuracy of infrared thermometer may not be that high comparing with a thermo-couple. Acutally, I use it only to get a rought estimation of the temperature, and in my case, the temperature is relatively high, larger than 1000 centigrade.

Comment: Infrared sensors measure surface temperature, as far as I know. I need to sense temperature in 3D.